# Why aren't a template's Sign Here fields being shown to the recipient with the API call

Tags: docusignapi

There is no error message but there is a mismatch between what occurs when I send a template from the DocuSign website versus when I send the template from the API.

I created a Template online with 4 documents. Later I added 4 required Sign Here fields for each.
When I send the document from the DocuSign website the recipient sees all the Sign Here fields and is required to sign all of them. Works beautifully.

When I send the template through the API it doesn't show any of the Sign Here fields. I could add one from the menu on the left of the webpage and it would let me finish but It's only one, not the required 4 that I added.
I am using the c# SDK to make API calls. I am creating an envelopeDefinition and assigning the templateId that I want to send then calling EnvelopesApi to create and send the Envelope.
Below is the code that I am using. It's almost copy and paste from the QuickStart

```
public static string SendEnvelopeViaEmailWithTemplate(string signerEmail, string signerName, string ccEmail,
            string ccName, string accessToken, string basePath,
            string accountId, string templateId)
        {

            var apiClient = GetApiClientObject();
            apiClient.Configuration.DefaultHeader.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
          
            var envelopesApi = GetEnvelopeApiObject();
            EnvelopeDefinition envelope = MakeEnvelopeFromTemplate(signerEmail, signerName, ccEmail, ccName, templateId);
            EnvelopeSummary result = envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope(accountId, envelope);
           
            return result.EnvelopeId;
        }

    private static EnvelopeDefinition MakeEnvelopeFromTemplate(string signerEmail, string signerName,
            string ccEmail, string ccName, string templateId)
            {
                
                EnvelopeDefinition env = new EnvelopeDefinition();
                env.TemplateId = templateId;
    
                TemplateRole signer1 = new TemplateRole();
                signer1.Email = signerEmail;
                signer1.Name = signerName;
                signer1.RoleName = "signer";
    
                TemplateRole cc1 = new TemplateRole();
                cc1.Email = ccEmail;
                cc1.Name = ccName;
                cc1.RoleName = "cc";
    
                env.TemplateRoles = new List<TemplateRole> { signer1, cc1 };
    
                env.Status = "sent";
                return env;
            }
```

Comment: The roleName "signer" is that what you put in the template? or did you mean that it's a signer vs. cc, which is not what this is

Comment: Oh. I changed the name to "signer" in the template and then it worked as expected. Thank you!

Comment: You could post this as the answer so I could accept it

Comment: I did post it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **roleName** must match the "placeholder" for recipients as defined in the template.
Did you really use "signer" for the **roleName**, or did you mean the recipient type is "signer" "cc" etc. which is not the same as **roleName**.